# tableselect didnt show any result

Tags: 7, forms

here the code i'm working

```
$query = db_select("aa_koleksi", "koleksi");
$query->fields("koleksi", array("id", "judul"));
$result = $query->execute();  
$header = array('Kode Buku', 'Judul Buku',);
$rows = array();

while($data = $result->fetchObject()){ 
$rows[] = array( 
  $data->id,
  $data->judul,      
);
}

$form['tabled'] = array(
'#type' => 'tableselect',
'#header' => $header,
'#options' => $rows,
'#multiple' => true,
'#empty' => t('No users found'),    
);

return $form;
```

the result is nothing only alert like

> Notice: Undefined index: #attributes in theme_tableselect() (line 3332 of C:\xampp\htdocs\kinta\includes\form.inc).

any suggestion??